# Running API tests in background

Tags: git, unit-testing, jenkins, automated-tests, mocha.js

I have close to 200 + test-cases in my code project. Well added the pre-commit whenever we push something in your master branch.

It runs 200 + cases and then pushes that particular commit. Can I run these test cases in a background process?

Please suggest me some good way to automate those.

P.S. Well I use Jenkins for continuous integration.

Comment: The traditional way is to never push on master directly. Create feature branches, commit and push on the feature branch. Let Jenkins build the feature branch, and if the tests pass and the feature branch is ready to be included, merge it to master.

Comment: @JBNizet If the merge is not fast-forward you still have to test master after merge.

Comment: @phd true, unless you rebase before merging (which I always do, to keep a linear history).

Comment: @JBNizet Doesn't matter — if you rebased you must test after rebase. :-)

Comment: Sure, but at this time, the code under test is still not on master.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "_run these test cases in a background process_"? Jenkins runs builds multi-threaded in parallel (depending on the no. of Build Executors you defined) and it can run builds on a cluster of slaves (each of them with its own executors).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a pre-commit is that it can easily be bypassed by the developer, who can push anyway.

You could establish an intermediate Git repo where developers would push.
A Jenkins job monitoring that repo would then launch the 200+ tests, and if they pass, would push to the final actual target Git repo.
If not, it would send an email to the commit author email in order to warn him/her of the commit rejection, and would revert that commit on the intermdiate gate-keeper repo.